# Why chromium don't apply corectly opacity CSS on <img> with position:absolute?

Tags: css, google-chrome, opacity, chromium

I have a problem with opacity CSS and Chrome. It's work fine with Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/79a4eb37/3/

Why `position: absolute` on img cancel the opacity to the second img?

I need apply opacity on all img in my div container. How can I do that?

Why dos't work with this code?

EDIT: bug are only on chromium, not chrome.

thx.

Comment: Do not see the problem - everything looks fine.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/79a4eb37/4/ here, without absolute position, the two images are semi-transparent, but here http://jsfiddle.net/79a4eb37/3/, works only on the first image.

Comment: Both links show the same semi-transparent second image. Update Chrome or it is your local problem (disable ABP or any other ad-blocker, Chrome addons).

Comment: @Cheery I use in fact Chromium (Version 37.0.2062.120 Ubuntu 14.04 (281580) (64-bit)), no ad-blocker used.

Comment: @Cheery Yes, I test with Chrome it's good, the problem is Chromium. How can I solved the problem? I have already the newest version...